# Eigenfunction Uniqueness Theorem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenfunctions, sturm-liouville

Consider the following Sturm-Liouville boundary value problem:

$\text{Given parameters }c > 0 \text{ and } \beta > 0, \text{ let } y=y(x) \text{ for } 0 \leq x \leq c. \text{ We have }$
$$y''+ \lambda y=0$$
$\text{ with boundary conditions }$
$$y'(0)=\beta y(0),$$
$$y'(c)=\beta y(c),$$

By supposing $y(x)=e^{kx}$, one can show that there is only one negative eigenvalue: $-\beta^2$

Is this the only eigenvalue? That is, there are no positive eigenvalues? I have heard that there is some sort of uniqueness theorem that guarantees this to be the case. What is this theorem? If it is the case that there are positive eigenvalues, what are they and how can one obtain them?

Comment: Did you derive that there is only one negative eigenvalue, or did you just read that somewhere? If you derived it assuming $\lambda < 0$ from the beginning, then you can derive it assuming $\lambda > 0$ from the beginning too. You can also derive it assuming $\lambda = 0$, to check if that's a valid eigenvalue.

Comment: What I did was use the supposition $y(x)=e^{kx}$ to see the differential equation can be written as $(k^2+\lambda)y=0$, so $k^2=-\lambda$. The boundary conditions yield $\pm i\sqrt{\lambda} = \beta$, hence $\lambda=-\beta^2$ I have already checked that $\lambda=0$ is not a valid eigenvalue, but I would like some clarification on potential positive eigenvalues.

Comment: Sure so if $\lambda > 0$, then you would use the form
$$y(x) = c_1 \cos(\sqrt{\lambda} x) + c_2 \sin(\sqrt{\lambda} x)$$
where $c_1, c_2 \in \mathbb{Z}$ could potentially be complex.

Comment: By the way, if you use $\lambda < 0$ for this BVP, typically, the solution that's taught would be of the form
$$ y(x) = c_1 \cosh(\sqrt{\lambda} x) + c_2 \sinh(\sqrt{\lambda} x) $$
for distinct values of $\sqrt{-\lambda}$.

Comment: You can find more information about it here: https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/de/BVPEvals.aspx

Comment: On a previous question, which I asked yesterday https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4807717/help-understanding-sturm-liouville-boundary-value-problem, I was wondering why for $\lambda < 0$ the answerer chose to let $y(x)=e^{kx}$. I am not sure how to obtain the eigenvalue $\lambda = -\beta^2$ from $y(x)=A\cosh(\sqrt{\lambda }x)+B\sinh(\sqrt{\lambda} x)$. I reach a dead end after trying to fiddle with the BVPs. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem in standard Sturm-Liouville form is:
$$
             y''+\lambda y = 0,\;\;\; 0 \le x \le c, \;\; c > 0, \\
       y'(0)-\beta y(0) = 0, \\
       y'(c)-\beta y(c) = 0.
$$
Start by solving
$$
            y''+\lambda y=0,\;\; 0 \le x \le c, \;\; c> 0, \\
       y(0)=1,\; y'(0)=\beta.
$$
This has the unique solution
$$
          y_{\lambda}(x)=\cos(\sqrt{\lambda}x)+\beta\frac{\sin(\sqrt{\lambda}x)}{\sqrt{\lambda}}.
$$
And, this solution works for $\lambda=0$ as well if you let $\lambda\rightarrow 0$:
$$
       y_0(x)=1+\beta x.
$$

Therefore, there is a non-trivial solution of the original problem for some $\lambda$ iff $y_{\lambda}'(c)-\beta y_{\lambda}(c)=0$, which gives the eigenvalue equation
$$
   0=-\sqrt{\lambda}\sin(\sqrt{\lambda}c)+\beta\cos(\sqrt{\lambda}c)
\\ -\beta\cos(\sqrt{\lambda}c)-\beta^2\frac{\sin(\sqrt\lambda c)}{\sqrt{\lambda}} \\
  = -\sqrt{\lambda}\sin(\sqrt{\lambda}c)
-\beta^2\frac{\sin(\sqrt\lambda c)}{\sqrt{\lambda}}.
$$
The limiting case where $\lambda\rightarrow 0$ has no non-trivial solution unless $\beta=0$. So $\lambda=0$ may be excluded if $\beta\ne 0$, which gives the general eigenvalue equation in $\lambda$:
$$   (\lambda+\beta^2)\sin(\sqrt{\lambda}c)=0,\;\;\lambda\ne 0.
$$
The eigenvalues are
$$
        \lambda=-\beta^2,\frac{n^2\pi^2}{c^2},\;\; n=1,2,3,\cdots.
$$
So, there is only one negative eigenvalue, but infinitely many positive eigenvalues.